# vb.net to import text file into excel delimited by spaces

Tags: vb.net, import, stream, text-files, readlines

was wondering if anyone has an example vb code to import a text file into excel delimited by spaces - regardless of number of spaces. In the text file there are for example 100k lines and in each line, each word can be separated by one, two or three etc spaces.

the result of the import into excel is that each line from the text file is in each row, and each word from each line separated by spaces are in each column of that row.

I tried to accomplish this by reading each line in the text file and then to parse each word for each line, and put these into a variable and then write it to excel. I think this way takes longer, and I am in the middle of parsing each line. But I think importing the text file into excel delimited by spaces is quicker if this can be done. The reason I use vb instead of vba is because vb can create an executable file which can be run by scheduler. Thanks

```
Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\test.txt")
Dim allLines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Dim stringreader As String
Dim a As String
    stringreader = filereader.ReadLine()

    Do While Not reader.EndOfStream
      allLines.Add(reader.ReadLine())
      stringreader = reader.ReadLine()
      MsgBox("The first line of the file is                " & stringreader)
    Loop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example `StreamReader` and `Excel` are opened first. Then new `Workbook` and new `Worksheet` are added. Finally the text file is read line by line. Each line is split on spaces and written to `Excel Worksheet`. After the text file was processed the `Stream` is closed and the `Excel` with the results remains opened. HTH

> Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies for your version of Excel.
>
> (Example uses reference to Ecel 2007 PIA: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\12.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll)

```
Imports System.IO
Imports ExcelInterop = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module Module2
   Sub Main()
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\test.txt")
        Dim targetWorksheet As ExcelInterop.Worksheet = GetTargetWorksheet("c:\test.xls")
        if targetWorksheet Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Try
            Dim line As String
            Dim lineIndex As Long = 1
            Do While reader.Peek() >= 0
                line = reader.ReadLine()
                WriteToExcel(line, targetWorksheet, lineIndex)
                lineIndex += 1 
            Loop
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        finally
            If Not reader Is Nothing Then
                reader.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

   Private Sub WriteToExcel(line As String, targetWorksheet As ExcelInterop.Worksheet, lineIndex As Long)
        Dim column As Integer = 1
        For Each part As String In line.Split(" ")
            targetWorksheet.Cells(lineIndex, column).Value =part
            column += 1
       Next
   End Sub

    Private Function GetTargetWorksheet(targetPath As String) As ExcelInterop.Worksheet
        Try
            Dim excelApplication = New ExcelInterop.Application
            excelApplication.Visible = True
            Dim excelWorkbook As ExcelInterop.Workbook
            excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add()
            excelWorkbook.SaveAs(targetPath)
            Dim excelWorksheet As ExcelInterop.Worksheet = excelWorkbook.Worksheets.Add()
            excelWorksheet.Name = "Import"
            return excelWorksheet
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("The excel worksheet could not be created:")
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Module
```

EDIT:

It is possible to use `QueryTables` of `Excel` to import text data. There are some settings to consider, like `TextFileColumnDataTypes`. Here in this example all the columns are set to `xlColumnDataType.xlTextFormat`.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim targetWorksheet As Worksheet = GetTargetWorksheet("c:\test.xls")
    if targetWorksheet Is Nothing Then
        Debug.WriteLine("Target sheet is Nothing.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Try
        Dim qt As QueryTable
        qt = targetWorksheet.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="TEXT;C:\test.txt", _
        Destination:=targetWorksheet.Range("$A$1"))

        With qt
            .Name = "Import"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = XlCellInsertionMode.xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 1252
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = GetColumnDataTypes(targetWorksheet.Columns.Count)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh(BackgroundQuery := False)
        End With
        
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function GetColumnDataTypes(queryTableColumnsCount As long) As Object
    Dim textDataTypes As xlColumnDataType()
    textDataTypes = Enumerable.Repeat(xlColumnDataType.xlTextFormat, queryTableColumnsCount).ToArray()
    Return textDataTypes          
End Function
```

Comment: Hi dee, thanks for the code example. It looks very good and works perfectly. Only things is that in a string from a line in text file, the spaces between each words can be unpredictable, it can have 1, 2, 3 or many more spaces. So I did searches on the internet to find a code that removes extra spaces and added to your writetoexcel function and it works like a charm. so now blanks are not write into excel column if there are extra spaces.

Comment: Anyway, with the code being great and all thanks to you, I was wondering if there is an ability in vb to import text file into excel and not read each line by line and write each line by line to excel. Import, I think is much quicker if for example for a large file that has 500k lines, if vb can't do this, that is fine too.  Thanks again for the great code !  :)

Comment: Thanks again dee for the wonderful and awesome codes. I think the edited portion are VBA and needs excel to run it. Was wondering if there is a vb.net version without going into vba and excel. If not that is fine to. I just thought I stop with VBA and learn vb.net instead. Cheers !

Comment: You are welcome! See edited answer, where the VBA code has been transformed to VB.NET code. It looks almost the same as VBA. To learn VB.NET is good idea! Don't wait, just start with VB.NET today...or at least tomorrow :).